# Calculate time() - minutes or hours or weeks or months or years PHP

Tags: php, time, unix-timestamp

I currently have a piece of code that fetch a string.

Exemple: 23 minutes ago

My code, if minutes, get the number (23 in this case).

I want to remove minutes (in this case) from the time() unix timestamp value.

I tried :

```
 $timestamplastcheck = strtotime("-".$minutes." minutes", strtotime(time()));
```

But it's returning wrong date.

Can someone told me what's wrong? and also, if hours, weeks, months, and years are added the same way?

Much appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use `Date` with date method `modify`, example:

```
$ago = '23 minutes ago';
$date = (new \DateTime())->modify($ago);
$timestamplastcheck = $date->getTimestamp()

echo $date->format('c');
```

With this you can't need parse your string to get the number, the `modify` is very powerful. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

Comment: How could I return $date->format('c'); in a timestamp unix as well? :p

Comment: `$date->getTimestamp()`

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime(time())` is nonsense and returns `false`.

`false` then gets casted to `0` by the other `strtotime()` call and all your relative time formats will be relative to `1.1.1970`.

The correct way would be to omit the second argument entirely since `time()` is its default value anyway:

```
$timestamplastcheck = strtotime("-".$minutes." minutes");
```